# Stronglooop loopback after remotehook couldn't modify response

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, strongloop

I want to added extra *details* on ***login request*** and I have the following

```
module.exports = function(UserAccount) {

UserAccount.afterRemote('login', function(ctx, result, next) {
    var response = [];

    if (ctx.result) {
        var userId = result.userId;
        var token = result.id;

        // attach user profile
        UserAccount.findById(userId, function(err, user) {
            if (err)
                console.log(err);
            if (user) {
                response.profile = user;
                response.accessToken = token;

                ctx.result = response;
                console.log(ctx.result);

                return next();

            }

        });

    }

});
```

};

the log just before the `next()` callback call logs correctly. 
The problem is that is always returns **empty response** .

What is the problem ?

Comment: your function doesn't return anything, could that be the problem?

Comment: @JaromandaX it think it does return the callback next() , BTW the response code is 200
and on the console I can get the response log.

Comment: that return is from an inner function - all I'm saying is your main function returns `undefined` - not saying that's your issue though

Comment: @JaromandaX Well about the main function , it is how strongloop works and I don't think that is the problem ,I think the problem is with the **asynchronous control flow**. I could use Promise here but I am getting the same result. If you want to see the promise version I can post snipt.

Comment: I'm wondering if the issue is that you're overwriting context.result. Rather than ctx.result=response, try ctx.result.profile=user and ctx.result.accessToken=token

Answer (score 0):

Just call `next()` instead of returning it. Also, modify `ctx.res.body` to modify the actual response body.